# Jasypt encryption too slow

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, jasypt

I am using Jasypt libary to encrypt/decrypt a large number of words because I found that Jasypt is easy to use over the standard Cryptography api , The problem is the decryption is very slow it take about 3 second to process 1000 words, I tried using fixed salt and small number of key iteration but the problem still there , This is the code I am using

```
StandardPBEByteEncryptor enc = new StandardPBEByteEncryptor();
enc.setSaltGenerator(new ZeroSaltGenerator());
enc.setKeyObtentionIterations(1);
enc.setPassword("@password");
```

Is there a way to get a better performance ?

Comment: *"Is there a way to get a better performance ?"* - Yes, use the plain Java cryptography API. Jasypt doesn't provide authenticity so you can derive a single key from the password yourself and re-use that key for encryption and decryption. The slow operation is the key derivation which is necessary for each encryption and decryption in Jasypt.

Comment: Key generation is intended to be slow to defeat brute force attacks.  Are you generating a new key for each word perhaps?  Try generating a new key every 10,000 words instead to see if that speeds things up.